# On `$scope.eventSource` the property `className` doesn't adds up - issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using `AngularJS` directive for the `Arshaw FullCalendar`. The problem is the `className` in `$scope.eventSource` is not showing-up on `event object` my code is:

```
$scope.eventSource = {
    url: "/unavailability/getCalData?userId=" + CurrentUser.user().id,// add source of working api
    className: 'performer-unavailability', // an option! -> Not Working
    currentTimezone: 'America/Chicago' // an option!
};
```

But when i send `className` from backend in event array it works fine, the `className` is attached to the event. I don't want to parse a whole lot of array in backend to add `className`, Please suggest any solution.

Answer (score -1):

How is event object built in the backend and is the url equivalent? If the event source is missing a title or start tag, options may not work.

> Event Objects can have "options" associated with them. However, before you can start specifying options, you must write an Event Object in its extended form. It must be a traditional JavaScript object with properties. Here are the extended forms for each type of Event Source:
>   http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Source_Object/

Comment: i have used fullcalendar for quite a long, and this functionality that angular is using can be achived, the classname property should be attached to every event thats why we are are specifying it there. i have raised an issue on git hub there is no reply yet.

Comment: If there weren't any events at  the "/unavailability/getCalData?userId=" + CurrentUser.user().id endpoint then this may happen. Should have read into your question and seen you were getting events bank. Sorry that it wasn't helpful and seems too simple.